# Sharing MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm working on a website to manage some database things for my company. I am using Visual Studio 2013 and the MVC framework.

I have the site working under the `http://localhost:275333/Home/PricingList` URL but my boss is old and crotchety and doesn't understand that he can't use that URL to view the site from his computer.

He wants to see the work i've done on the site but I'm not sure how to send him a link that will work on his machine.

Any help?

Comment: do you have a local web server in the network ? publish your site there and share the url

Comment: Yes. but the guy who manages all of that is out on vacation. Which doesn't bode well for my situation

Comment: you should also take vacation until he is back the office :)

Comment: You could install IIS or IIS Express on your local PC, publish your application using that and open the relevant ports in your firewall (assuming company policy permits all of that *and* that your boss' PC is on the same intranet as yours - I assume you don't mean his home PC!)

Comment: That's a cool port number.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IIS Express? If so, read this Scott Hanselman [post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx) - one of the items he discusses is allowing access from other PCs

Answer (score 0):

**IF** your machine is visible from their machine you can do the following:

Install IIS Express on your machine:

- open Windows Explorer
- click on the system drive (C:) in the folder panel
- find the "Uninstall or change a program" button above the files list, click
- find "Turn Windows features on or off" on the left of the window that pops up, click  - check everything "Internet Information Services"
- click ok, possibly restart

From Visual Studio set your project to use IIS Express, publish it locally. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178108.ASPX) for further assistance with that.

Find the IP of your machine by running `ipconfig` in a [console](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/947-command-prompt.html)

Send a link that looks like this: 'http ://(your_ip_here)/(optional_site_name)/index.html'

**IF** your machine is not visible you would have to make your own VPN, which is a subject of [another post](http://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/).